# Problema com recursividade ao integrar arquivos

Tags: c#, winforms, recursão

estou fazendo uma integração recursiva de vários arquivos,quando executo com somente um arquivo ele integra normal, mas quando eu tento integrar varios arquivos ele da esse erro.

```
    {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}
```

olhando o Inner Exception eu encotro isso

```
    {"Parameter value '99999,999' is out of range."}
```

mas o mesmo arquivo sendo integrado sozinho não apresenta o erro
segue abaixo o meu código

```
private void ProcessarCEP(int i,FileInfo file,string [] Lines)
    {
        string vNomeArquivo = string.Empty;
        DBCEPEntities DBCEP = new DBCEPEntities();
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(file.DirectoryName);
        FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        int vTamanhoBase = DBCEP.CAD_CEP.Where(t => t.UF == file.Name.Substring(15,2)).Count();

        for (int a = vTamanhoBase; a < i + vTamanhoBase; a++)
            {
                if (a >= Lines.Count()) break;

                CAD_CEP CEP = new CAD_CEP();
                string[] Registros = Lines[a].Split('@');

                CEP.CEP = Convert.ToDecimal(Registros[7]);
                CEP.UF = Registros[1];
                CEP.LOGRADOURO = Registros[8];
                CEP.ENDERECO = Registros[5];
                if (Registros[2] != string.Empty)
                {
                    decimal CodLocal = Convert.ToDecimal(Registros[2]);
                    var local = DBCEP.CAD_CIDADE.Where(c => c.CODLOCAL == CodLocal).FirstOrDefault();
                    CEP.LOCAL = local.LOCAL;
                }
                if (Registros[3] != string.Empty)
                {
                    decimal CodBairro = Convert.ToDecimal(Registros[3]);
                    var bairro = DBCEP.CAD_BAIRRO.Where(c => c.CODBAIRRO == CodBairro).FirstOrDefault();
                    CEP.BAIRRO = bairro.BAIRRO;
                }
                vNomeArquivo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NomeArquivoSequencia"].ToString();
                if (files.Where(f => f.Name.ToUpper() == vNomeArquivo.ToUpper()).Count() > 0)
                {
                    if (Registros[0] != string.Empty)
                    {
                        string[] LinesSec = File.ReadAllLines(files.Where(f => f.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith(vNomeArquivo.ToUpper())).FirstOrDefault().FullName.ToString(), Encoding.Default);
                        string vLinhaSec = LinesSec.Where(l => l.StartsWith(Registros[0] + "@")).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (vLinhaSec != null)
                        {
                            string[] vLinhaSplit = vLinhaSec.Split('@');

                            if (vLinhaSplit[1] != string.Empty)
                            {
                                CEP.DE = Convert.ToDecimal(vLinhaSplit[1]);
                            }
                            if (vLinhaSplit[2] != string.Empty)
                            {
                                CEP.ATE = Convert.ToDecimal(vLinhaSplit[2]);
                            }
                            CEP.FL_PAR_IMPAR = vLinhaSplit[3];
                        }
                        Registros = null;
                        LinesSec = null;
                    }
                }
                DBCEP.CAD_CEP.Add(CEP);
            }
            DBCEP.SaveChanges();
            vTamanhoBase = DBCEP.CAD_CEP.Where(t => t.UF == file.Name.Substring(15, 2)).Count();
            DBCEP.Dispose();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();

            if (Lines.Count() <= i + vTamanhoBase)
            {
               if(vTamanhoBase != Lines.Count())
               {
                   ProcessarCEP(Lines.Count() - i, file, Lines);
               }                    
            }
            else
            {
                if(vTamanhoBase != Lines.Count())
                {
                    ProcessarCEP(i, file, Lines);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Ai. Deu medo!!!

Answer (score 0):

"Out of range" o seu "for" está tentando acessar uma posição do vetor que não existe. Lembre-se que count retorna a quantidade e não a posição. Exemplo

```
var t = Lista.Count // vai me retornar a quantidade de elementos
for(var i = 1; i <= t; i++)
`{`
   `var elemento = lista[i] - 1;`
`}`
```

Comment: Não pode ser isso porque quando eu integro somente esse arquivo ele vai tranquilo. Se fosse pelo vetor ele não integraria nem sozinho nem acompanhado. O erro que da não é Index Out of Range

Comment: @RafaelArnosti refatora seu código, cria métodos de apoio para facilitar o debug.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o motivo quando ele esta integrando mais de um arquivo no arquivo de que ele faz referencia nessa parte

```
       vNomeArquivo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NomeArquivoSequencia"].ToString();
            if (files.Where(f => f.Name.ToUpper() == vNomeArquivo.ToUpper()).Count() > 0)
            {
                if (Registros[0] != string.Empty)
                {
                    string[] LinesSec = File.ReadAllLines(files.Where(f => f.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith(vNomeArquivo.ToUpper())).FirstOrDefault().FullName.ToString(), Encoding.Default);
                    string vLinhaSec = LinesSec.Where(l => l.StartsWith(Registros[0] + "@")).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (vLinhaSec != null)
                    {
                        string[] vLinhaSplit = vLinhaSec.Split('@');

                        if (vLinhaSplit[1] != string.Empty)
                        {
                            CEP.DE = Convert.ToDecimal(vLinhaSplit[1]);
                        }
                        if (vLinhaSplit[2] != string.Empty)
                        {
                            CEP.ATE = Convert.ToDecimal(vLinhaSplit[2]);
                        }
                        CEP.FL_PAR_IMPAR = vLinhaSplit[3];
                    }
```

esta com valores que estouram o campo na base sql por isso o erro é

```
      {"Parameter value '99999,999' is out of range."}
```